# Custom sound in Android Push Notifications (GCM )

Tags: android, cordova, audio, push-notification

How can I play a custom sound when receiving an Android Push Notification?

Within the app I can control this by using the media player. Outside the APP I can not find the correct path to the audio file . I already have "/android_assets/www/" tried "www/", but there is always the default sound when you receive a push notification outside the app.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you would need to add the new sound file in raw folder under the res folder.

Since it is cordova Application,you are using Cordova push Plugin.There is a package called com.plugin.gcm.In that package open GCMIntentService.java.Under the

```
    public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
```

method ,there should be a line at the end of this method

```
    mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Just replace the line with the following codes

```
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/your_sound_file_name.mp3");
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Somehow, it didnt work for me when i put my sound file in res folder. Instead i created "raw" folder inside "res" folder in my android project and it worked. Not sure what is wrong my configuration.

Comment: Sorry @SaravananS ,this is not your fault ,I forgot to mention to keep the file into raw under the res folder,otherwise it wont work,because when you have different R's. you are simply not referencing the right R.
Actually raw resources are not compiled by the platform.So that android can create a reference to the particular raw file. like R.raw.filename
I have updated my answer.Please mark it as useful.

Comment: Hi there, this works great - but the odd part is the same file volume is great when played in foreground, but when used for push notification, the volume is very low - cranking up the phone volume doesn't help either. Is there any way to bump up the volume of the media file when the push is delivered?